# Conversion Warning with Bitwise Or and Casted Operands

Tags: c, casting, integer-promotion, bitwise-or, uint16

Code Snippet 1 (shown below) produces the following -Wconversion warning:

```
debug_Wconversion.c:10:57: warning: conversion to ‘uint16_t’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     result = ((uint16_t) (((uint16_t) byte1) & 0x0050)) | ((uint16_t) byte2);
                                                         ^
```

Code snippets 2 and 3 do not produce a -Wconversion warning.

Code Snippet 1:

```
uint8_t  byte1 = 0xF0;
uint8_t  byte2 = 0x0F;
uint16_t result;
result = ((uint16_t) (((uint16_t) byte1) & 0x0050)) | ((uint16_t) byte2);
```

Code Snippet 2:

```
uint8_t  byte1 = 0xF0;
uint8_t  byte2 = 0x0F;
uint16_t result;
uint16_t leftOrOperand;
uint16_t rightOrOperand;
leftOrOperand  = ((uint16_t) (((uint16_t) byte1) & 0x0050));
rightOrOperand = ((uint16_t) byte2);
result = leftOrOperand | rightOrOperand;
```

Code Snippet 3:

```
uint8_t  byte1 = 0xF0;
uint8_t  byte2 = 0x0F;
uint16_t result;
result = (uint16_t) (((uint16_t) (((uint16_t) byte1) & 0x0050)) | ((uint16_t) byte2));
```

Why does the first code snippet produce the warning, but the others do not?  What specifically is causing the warning?

I find this perplexing.  The warning in the first snippet insinuates that integer promotion is occurring in the Bitwise Or operation, despite the explicit casting of the operands.  The second snippet demonstrates that the Bitwise Or operation does not inherently cause integer promotion.  The third snippet performs the same operation as the first snippet if order of operations is preserved, but casts the result of the Bitwise Or before assignment of the result variable.  There is clearly something that I fail to understand about the interplay between casting and the Bitwise Or operation.  Any help with clarifying my comprehension would be greatly appreciated!

Other potentially relevant information:

- gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623  (I am unable to upgrade, but this also seems to occur on newer versions)
- -std=c11
- -Wconversion warning is present with default optimization (no supplied setting) and with disabled optimization (-O0)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try unsigned constants `0x0050` --> `0x0050u`.  Use `unsigned` math instead of `int` math.

Comment: FWIW, all these casts are totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the bitwise OR operator `|` and the bitwise AND operator `&` perform integer promotions on both operands.  The fact that one of the operands is the result of a cast doesn't change this.

The `-Wconversion` flag tends to be a bit overenthusiastic regarding what it warns on.  Given a 32-bit `int`, a conversion from `uint16_t` to `int` will **not** change its value.

The C standard does specify that the minimum range of an `int` is -32767 to 32767, so an implementation with this limit could potentially see a value change, though you'll be hard-pressed to find a system the runs gcc where this is the case.

This particular warning is silenced however by a cast.  From the man page:

> -Wconversion
>
> Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value. This includes
> conversions between real and integer, like "abs (x)" when "x" is
> "double";    conversions between signed and unsigned, like "unsigned
> ui = -1"; and conversions to smaller types, like "sqrtf (M_PI)". **Do
> not warn for    explicit casts like "abs ((int) x)" and "ui =
> (unsigned) -1"**, or if the value is not changed by the conversion like
> in "abs (2.0)".  Warnings    about conversions between signed and
> unsigned integers can be disabled by using -Wno-sign-conversion.
>
> For C++, also warn for confusing overload resolution for
> user-defined conversions; and conversions that never use a type
> conversion operator:    conversions to "void", the same type, a base
> class or a reference to them. Warnings about conversions between
> signed and unsigned integers are    disabled by default in C++ unless
> -Wsign-conversion is explicitly enabled.

Comment: This answer provides a thorough yet precise explanation of the fundamental elements of compiler implementation (and reasoning) that give rise to the behavior in the original question.  Thanks, @dbush.  Your info helped clarify this.  It was bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the first code snippet produce the warning, but the others do not? What specifically is causing the warning?

`((uint16_t) (((uint16_t) byte1) & 0x0050)) | ((uint16_t) byte2)` is an `int` being assigned to a `uint16_t`.

`((uint16_t) (((uint16_t) byte1) & 0x0050))` is a `uint16_t`.
`((uint16_t) byte2)` is also a  `uint16_t`.
`uint16_t | uint16_t` first promotes the operands to `int` before the `|`.

Code is assigning an `int` to a `uint16_t` - hence the warning.

In the 2nd  snippet, the compiler better understands or'ing two `uint16_t` (result is also `int`) will not incur a conversion issue down-converting to `uint16_t`.  The first was just a tad too complex for the compiler to deduce no issue.

In the 3rd, the final cast silenced any down conversion issue.

---

Alternative: Use an `unsigned` constant: `0x0050u` and `unsigned` math for *unsigned* types like `uint16_t`.

```
uint8_t  byte1 = 0xF0u;
uint8_t  byte2 = 0x0Fu;
//                 v-------------v unsigned result
//                         v-----v unsigned constant
uint16_t result = (byte1 & 0x0050u) | byte2;
//                ^-----------------------^ unsigned result
//       ^--------------------------------^ initializing: unsigned to uint16_t
```

A pesky compiler may still whine about the narrowing initialization.

```
// Non-cast alternative
uint16_t result = UINT16_MAX & ((byte1 & 0x0050u) | byte2);
// Cast alternative
uint16_t result = (uint16_t)   ((byte1 & 0x0050u) | byte2);
```

Comment: **Future readers should read this answer too.** This answer very nicely compliments the accepted answer, as it quite clearly walks through the code snippets providing clear, concise, and grokable explanations of the behavior in each.  Thank you, @chux, for your nearly instantaneous response and useful suggestions!  And thank you for making stackoverflow the invaluable resource that it is.